# Flatlist so atualiza quando eu salvo o codigo - React native

Tags: firebase, react-native, mobile

Eu estou fazendo um app usando react native e firebase, ele esta pronto, mas estou tendo um ultimo problema, toda vez que eu insiro um novo produto ou atualizo um, ele não renderiza automatico, porem, quando eu dou control-s no vscode ele renderiza, como eu faço pra ele já ir automatico?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView , ImageBackground, TextInput, Button, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView, CheckBox, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '../config/firebaseconfig'
import Item from './Item'
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

export default function veiculos_cadastrados(props){

    const user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    const [data, setData] = useState([]) 

    const getUsers = () =>{
        firebase.firestore().collection('Carros').where("Usuario", "==", user_id).get().then((querySnapshot)=>{
            let d = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                //console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data())
                const user = {
                    id: doc.id,
                    Ano: doc.data().Ano,
                    Potencia: doc.data().Potencia,
                    Carro: doc.data().Carro,
                    Quilometragem: doc.data().Quilometragem,
                    Oleo: doc.data().Oleo,
                    Gasolina: doc.data().Gasolina,
                    Tanque: doc.data().Tanque
                }
                d.push(user);
            })
            setData(d);
        })
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        getUsers();
    }, [])

    
        const [task, setTask] = useState([]);
       
        function deleteTask(id) {
            firebase.firestore().collection("Carros").doc(id).delete();
            alert("Veículo excluido com sucesso!")
        }
       
        useEffect(() => {
            firebase.firestore().collection("Carros").onSnapshot((query) => {
            const list = [];
            query.forEach((doc) => {
              list.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
            });
            setTask(list);
          });
        }, []);
    
    const renderItem = ({item}) =>(
        <Item item={item} onPress={() => routeUser(item)}/>
    )

    return(
        <View>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
            contentContainerStyle={styles.box} keyboardVerticalOffset="-240" behavior="position" enabled
            >
                <View style={styles.fundo}>

                <View style={styles.menu}>
                    <Text
                    style={styles.menu_text} 
                    onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate('menu')}>Menu</Text>

                </View>

                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.main_text}>Meus veículos</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View>
                        
                        <FlatList
                        scrollEnabled={true}
                        style={styles.flat}
                        data={data}
                        renderItem={({item}) => (
                            
                            <View style={styles.fundo_flat}>
                                    <Text style={styles.text_Carro}>{item.Carro}</Text>
                                    <View style={styles.flat_description}>
                                        <Text style={styles.text_flat}>Potência: {item.Potencia}</Text>
                                        <Text style={styles.text_flat}>Ano: {item.Ano}</Text>
                                        <Text style={styles.text_flat}>Km: {item.Quilometragem * 1}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    
                                    <View style={styles.flat_description2}>
                                        <Text style={styles.text_flat}>Precisa fazer troca de óleo em: {item.Quilometragem - item.Oleo}km</Text>
                                    </View>

                                    

                                    <View style={styles.flat_description2}>
                                        <Text style={styles.text_flat}>Km/Litro: {((item.Quilometragem - item.Gasolina) / item.Tanque) * 1}</Text>
                                    </View>

                                    <View style={styles.flat_buttons}>
                                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.editScreenButton}>
                                            <Text onPress={() => {
                                                deleteTask(item.id)
                                            }} 
                                                  style={styles.edit_Text}>Excluir</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                        
                                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.editScreenButton}>
                                            <Text onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate('editar_carro')}
                                                  style={styles.edit_Text}>Atualizar</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                    
                            </View>
                        )}
                        />
                        
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.button_login}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginScreenButton}>
                            <Text onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate('cadastrar_veiculo')} style={styles.login_Text}>+ Cadastrar</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere o seu `setData(d);` na função `getUsers()` para `setData([...d]);` que já deve funcionar.

Caso não funcionar, você pode usar o [`extraData`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) da FlatList, passando um state booleano e alternando ele entre `true` e `false` sempre que quiser renderizar novamente sua lista